# English writers IDE

Tags: tools, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a special software for writers?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9/is-there-a-special-software-for-writers)

What IDE's do writers typically write in?  I'm aware of Microsoft Word, but surely that is not something that a professional writer uses (one that's writing for a book publisher)?  Would they be using something like LaTeX?

Comment: @Alenanno, I'm very sorry, I didn't even know there was a Writers SE.

Comment: @Alenanno, how do I transfer this question there?

Comment: @KerxPhilo: No worries! Actually I think it would transfer itself if enough people vote for it (I voted, but for now I'm the only one)... Let's wait for someone else, I'm not sure on this matter, I can only vote for now :)

Comment: Welcome, @KerkPhilo As @RegDwight pointed out, this is very similar to an existing question. So, even though I'm voting to close this one, I'm sure everyone hopes you stick around to ask more questions about writing.

Comment: @Craig, thank you very much. I would have never posted this question if I knew about Writers SE.  I did a search on the English SE and something like this didn't come up.  I'll definitely be sticking around.

Comment: Welcome aboard, then! :D

Answer (score 3):

For longer works I use [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php). But this is really more of a question for Writers.SE. See one [answer I posted there](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/how-do-you-calculate-the-length-of-your-manuscript/2372#2372), as well as several others on this topic at that site.

Comment: Gasp! Someone beat Lauren Ipsum to the Scrivener rec!